# Can we paint the plane in two colors such that there is no square of the same color?

Tags: coloring, combinatorial-geometry

We have our every day plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ which we want to paint using two colors in such a way that no four points form a square of the same color. This means that for any square on the plane its vertices have different colors.

Is it possible to paint a plane in such a way?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I have been thinking about using tools like in the two point set problem. Do you think it is a good approach?